# Append text from html into different section

Tags: javascript, html, dom, append, appendchild

Im trying to iterate through this html and get the h4 headers and the first sentence of each section and then append it into a div.

```
function sumary () {
let headings = document.getElementsByTagName("h4"); // Get H4s
let newsText = document.getElementsByClassName("newsarticle").firstChild; // gets first "P" from 
each "class="Newsarticle"
let menu = document.createElement("div");          // Create DIV
let menuUList = document.createElement("ul");     // Create UL
menu.appendChild(menuUList);                      // Append UL to DIV
for (let i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
    let menuUListItem = document.createElement("li"); // Create an LI for each H4 text
    menuUList.appendChild(menuUListItem); // Append the LI to the UL
    let menuUListItemLink = document.createElement("a"); // Create a A for each LI
    menuUListItem.appendChild(menuUListItemLink); // Append the A to the LI
    let linkText = headings[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue; // Find the text content of each H4
    let menuText = document.createTextNode(linkText); // Create a text node out of each H4 text
    menuUListItemLink.appendChild(menuText); // Append the text node to the A element
    document.body.insertBefore(menu, document.body.firstChild); //Insert into HTML
}

window.onload = makeNavMenu;
```

this is the html, i can get the h4 to display but they dont display under the  id= Headlines under the h2 heading.

```
<body>
<div id="wrappermain">
<h1>........</h1>

    <section id="headlines">
        <h2>.....</h2>  
    </section>

    <section id="news">
        <h3>......</h3>
        <article class="newsarticle">
            <h4>........</h4>
            <p>........</p>
            <p></p>
        </article>
        <article class="newsarticle">
            <h4>.......</h4>
            <p>.....</p>
        </article>
        <article class="newsarticle">
            <h4>.....</h4>
            <p>.......</p>  
        </article>
        <article class="newsarticle">
            <h4>....</h4>
            <p>.......</p>  
            <p>.......</p>  
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't try to run the code, but it appears the variable newsText is never used. Is this the bit that is missing you are expecting to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply appending the menu every iteration of the loop into the body at:

```
document.body.insertBefore(menu, document.body.firstChild); //Insert into HTML
```

This says that `menu` should be added before the `firstChild` in the body. And because it is inside `for` loop it will added for every `h4` element in your document. So move it outside of the loop.

You should select your destination and add the menu there. Like the following

```
const target = document.querySelector('#headlines'); // Select <section id="headlines">.
target.insertAdjecentElement('beforeend', menu); // Adds menu to the end in headlines.
```